# UIBarButtonItems selected color won't change properly in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

So I'm having issues with UIBarButtonItem appearances in iOS 7. There's a property which I can't find any documentation for that seems to set the opacity of navigation bar buttons when pressed, and I don't know how to modify it.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

For this code, the result I get is shown below.

[image: Normal Button]
[image: Highlighted Button]

I'm not sure what's going on here. The first problem is that I can't seem to get the arrow to tint (because there's no setTintColor:forState: method). The second problem is this awful opacity/tint when pressed. Thanks!

Comment: for that you have to set the uiimage selected/unselected.

Comment: are you found a solution for text color?

Answer (score 1):

// Customizing the Back Bar Buttons  paste this code in appdelegate

```
UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back_textured_30"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
UIImage *buttonBack24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back_textured_24"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 5)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack24
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Comment: I'm actually only looking to tint the text, not set the image!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this below two method in ios7 for `UIBarButtonItem`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor
- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Comment: I'm only trying to tint the text, not set the background image. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution it may work

```
  NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary        dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont 
fontWithName:@"YOURFONT" size:14], NSFontAttributeName, 
[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```